# Connecting to Dynamixel Bus Tutorial

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following Dynamixel tutorials on ROS Wiki.
http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus

In Step 2 : Create a launch file for the manager node, The code of the controller_manager.launch file is not visible.

I tried going to the web address but there it shows some kind of error on that page.

Can anyone fix this or get me that code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237854/connecting-to-dynamixel-bus-tutorial/) by [Astronirav](https://answers.ros.org/users/27124/astronirav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Code moved to GitHub: https://github.com/arebgun/dynamixel_motor/blob/master/dynamixel_tutorials/launch/controller_manager.launch

Will fix the wiki once I have write permissions.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-06-24**:
Updated wiki just now.